# Angular $scope with variable

Tags: angularjs

let's say I have the tutorial's code from AngularJS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);   
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.phones = [
        {'name': 'Nexus S',
         'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
        {'name': 'Motorola XOOM with Wi-Fi',
         'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
        {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM',
         'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}   
    ]; 
});
```

Now let's say i want to replace all the part where "name" and "snippet" is declared with an array with my informations. is that possible?

Comment: Try it, and if you have a problem, then come back with a concrete question. The answer to your question is Yes.

Comment: Yes, but if you're asking this first you might look into JavaScript and understand what objects, their properties and values are.

Answer (score 0):

Your question, as I understand it, is can a JavaScript object include an embedded array.  The answer is yes:.

Something like this:

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp', []);   myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.phones = [
    {'name': ['string1','string2','string3','string4'],
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': [1,2,3,4,5],
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': [{'prop':'value'},{'prop':'value2'},{'prop':1},{'prop':2} ],
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}   ]; });
```

Your $scope.phones is already an array.  I replaced the first items name property with an array of strings.  The second items name property is an array of numbers.  The third items name property with an array of objects.

[Code written in browser and not tested, but conceptually this is correct]